# ASP.NET MVC3 Web application deployment and code encryption

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I have developed an Accounting application in ASP.NET MVC3. It is a premise installed solution.

My concern is the security of my code. Is there any application like ioncube for ASP.NET applications ? or which is the best encryption solution for ASP.NET applications ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a .NET obfuscator. This answer can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988451/net-obfuscation